# Remove all but one row with duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three columns: `KEY`, `VALUE` and `LAST_UPDATED`

There are duplicate `VALUE` fields.  I want to delete all the rows which have the same `VALUE` as others *except* for the most recently updated one.

So if the table contained these rows:

```
1, "A", 2013-11-08
2, "B", 2013-10-30
3, "A", 2013-11-07
4, "A", 2013-11-01
5, "B", 2013-11-01
```

Then I want to keep just these rows:

```
1, "A", 2013-11-08
5, "B", 2013-11-01
```

How can you do this in SQL?  I imagine `DELETE FROM table WHERE key IN (SELECT key FROM table GROUP BY value HAVING count(*)>1)` would delete a single random(?) row from those which are duplicate values, but how to make it remove *all but* the most-recently-updated row?

Comment: Well, I guess the question would be this. Is there a field in there that can let us know which one was the most recently updated one?

Comment: In T-SQL you can do that with **`row_number() over(partition by order by LAST_UPDATED desc)`**. Just give a try to similar approach in MYSQL.

Comment: @neoistheone the `LAST_UPDATED` column

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: @DMac the question you link to does not try and keep a specific row, which is why the SQL answering the questions is so different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a left join:

```
DELETE t
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t.value = t2.value
AND t2.last_updated > t.last_updated
WHERE t2.key IS NOT NULL
```

This means for every row it looks for another row with a more recent update date, if there is one then the row will be deleted. You might have to look at doing a date diff instead of using greater than for comparing the dates as it is more reliable.

I would expect the performance of a left join to be far better in this case than creating and joining to an inline table but if performance is an issue then it may be best to try both ways and pick the one that most consistently performs the best.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
DELETE t FROM myTable t
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT VALUE,MAX(LAST_UPDATED) as mostRecent 
 FROM myTable 
 GROUP BY VALUE
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1           
) t2 ON t.VALUE = t2.VALUE 
     AND t.LAST_UPDATED != t2.mostRecent;
```

Comment: very cleaned solution

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I prefer the other solution because your solution uses a subquery - which isn't necessary. Just do a self-join, as collusionbdbh shows.

Comment: aha. Understand. I think I prefer the `LEFT JOIN` approach myself come to think of it....